# A Simple approach to implementing a multi level library with only one parent node, especially with MVC3/EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I am trying to implement a multi level library. There are only single parent nodes:

```
Parent1
   - Child1
   - Child2
Parent2
   - Child1
   - Child2
```

I started by implementing this using a link table

```
LibraryItem -< LibraryItemLink (FkParentId)
            -< LibraryItemLink (FkChildId)
```

Which is fine, and powerful since it allows for multiparent nodes as well as multichild nodes. However I have got into difficulties when trying to delete parent library items. Ideally one should put a "Cascade Delete" on both of the constraints to cover parent or child node deletion, but SQL Server does not like this as it think cyclic deletion may happen. So I wondered whether I was making life to tricky for myself and instead should use a self referencing association to LibraryItem.

```
LibraryItem -< LibraryItem(Children)
```

Would this be easier to implement, especially from a CRUD perspective within the MVC3/EF5 world?

The final option is 2 table for 2 levels which is much easier, but more limited.

Thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a PARENT_ID column in the `LibraryItem` table, allowing for NULLS and a FK back to the PK of the same table.

For your cascading delete issue, I would use a `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger on that table that;

1. Deletes all reocrds where the PARENT_ID is the PK of the row being deleted
2. Then delete the record of the parent itself.

Comment: Thanks. Always good to have another opinion. Never thought of "INSTEAD OF" trigger.